# Добавление максимального значения на график Ганта

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, график, визуализация

Есть следующий график (это экземпляр из нескольких однотипных графиков)

Как можно к нему добавить вывод максимального значения (в виде точки или полоски с самим значением) для каждой полосы:

Ожидаемый результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Датасет: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pED4oFOuCcbZyoSuh_F-uUM7yuT6Ff0n/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100335429201323787767&rtpof=true&sd=true

Мой код:

```
df2 = pd.read_excel(file2)
df2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(15,8))
operation_lenght = df2.Duration

bars = ax.barh(df2.Operation, df2.Duration, left=df2.Start, color=df2.Color)
ax.bar_label(bars, label_type='edge', padding = 5.0, labels = df2["Duration"], fontsize= 15)
ax.set_xlabel('Duration')
ax.set_ylabel('Operations')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот так примерно, дальше красоту наводите уже сами:

```
max_x = df2['Duration'].sum()
for b in bars:
    plt.plot([max_x, max_x], [b.get_y(), b.get_y() + b.get_height()], 'r')
    plt.text(max_x, b.get_y(), max_x, fontsize=24, color='blue')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо!
А в том случае, если операции могут выполняться параллельно и в датасете, в отдельной колонке, есть значение общей длительности процесса, то как можно рядом с красными полосами выводить для каждой операции значение длительности процесса?
То есть вместо max_x = df2['Duration'].sum(), как корректно передать значение из колонки df2['Length']?

Comment: @AlexMorgan Что-то я так не могу сходу сообразить. Наверное, это нужно заново задавать вопрос и рисовать, что вы хотите видеть.